# Any way to modify Jasmine spies based on arguments?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jasmine

I have a function I'd like to test which calls an external API method twice, using different parameters. I'd like to mock this external API out with a Jasmine spy, and return different things based on the parameters. Is there any way to do this in Jasmine? The best I can come up with is a hack using andCallFake:

```
var functionToTest = function() {
  var userName = externalApi.get('abc');
  var userId = externalApi.get('123');
};


describe('my fn', function() {
  it('gets user name and ID', function() {
    spyOn(externalApi, 'get').andCallFake(function(myParam) {
      if (myParam == 'abc') {
        return 'Jane';
      } else if (myParam == '123') {
        return 98765;
      }
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Why did you feel `and.callFake` was a hack? Looks like a good/best answer to me.

Answer (score 312, accepted):

In Jasmine versions 3.0 and above you can use `withArgs`

```
describe('my fn', function() {
  it('gets user name and ID', function() {
    spyOn(externalApi, 'get')
      .withArgs('abc').and.returnValue('Jane')
      .withArgs('123').and.returnValue(98765);
  });
});
```

For Jasmine versions earlier than 3.0 `callFake` is the right way to go, but you can simplify it using an object to hold the return values

```
describe('my fn', function() {
  var params = {
    'abc': 'Jane', 
    '123': 98765
  }

  it('gets user name and ID', function() {
    spyOn(externalApi, 'get').and.callFake(function(myParam) {
     return params[myParam]
    });
  });
});
```

Depending on the version of Jasmine, the syntax is slightly different:

- 1.3.1: `.andCallFake(fn)`
- 2.0: `.and.callFake(fn)`

**Resources:**

- [withArgs docs](https://jasmine.github.io/api/3.0/Spy.html#withArgs)
- [callFake docs](http://jasmine.github.io/edge/introduction.html#section-Spies:_%3Ccode%3Eand.callFake%3C/code%3E)
- [andCallFake vs and.callFake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22041745/jasmine-spyonobj-method-andcallfake-or-and-callfake)

Comment: This is now `and.callFake` - http://jasmine.github.io/2.2/introduction.html#section-Spies:_<code>and.callFake</code>

Comment: I had to return different promises, so the return looked slightly different: return q.when(params[myParam]);. Otherwise, this was a spot on solution to my problem. My dream solution would be to change "and.returnValue" calls.

Comment: feels like jasmine should have a better way of declaring this. Like `spyOn(fake, 'method').withArgs('abc').and.returnValue('Jane')` and `spyOn(fake, 'method').withArgs('123').and.returnValue(98765)`.

Comment: @jrharshath `.withArgs` is not working for me in jasmine 2.0

Comment: `.withArgs` is not really available - I meant that such a method would make sense when writing tests.

Comment: @jrhashath I'm not really sure if that would be much better. With the call fake your can do the same thing with conditional logic

Comment: See here for Jasmine contributors comments on this:
https://github.com/jasmine/jasmine/issues/32
(Helped me understand what needed to be done in code)

Comment: Jasmine 3.0 add support for this.

Answer (score 13):

You could also use `$provide` to create a spy. And mock using `and.returnValues` instead of `and.returnValue` to pass in parameterised data.

> **As per Jasmine docs:** By chaining the spy with `and.returnValues`, all calls to the function will return specific values in order until it reaches the end of the return values list, at which point it will return undefined for all subsequent calls.

```
describe('my fn', () => {
    beforeEach(module($provide => {
        $provide.value('externalApi', jasmine.createSpyObj('externalApi', ['get']));
    }));

        it('get userName and Id', inject((externalApi) => {
            // Given
            externalApi.get.and.returnValues('abc','123');

            // When
            //insert your condition

            // Then
            // insert the expectation                
        }));
});
```

Comment: This is the correct answer, since a test should always know exactly how a spy will be called, and therefore should just use `returnValues` to support multiple calls

Comment: Just to clarify akhouri's answer: this method only works when the 
`externalApi.get.and.returnValues('abc','123')` is called within the `it` function. Otherwise if you set a list of values, else where, it shall never work because the order in which tests are ran is not predictable. In fact tests should not depend on the order in which they are executed.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had a component I was testing and, in its constructor, there is a config service with a method called **getAppConfigValue** that is called twice, each time with different arguments:

```
constructor(private configSvc: ConfigService) {
  this.configSvc.getAppConfigValue('a_string');
  this.configSvc.getAppConfigValue('another_string');
}
```

In my spec, I provided the ConfigService in the TestBed like so:

```
{
  provide: ConfigService,
  useValue: {
    getAppConfigValue: (key: any): any {
      if (key === 'a_string) {
        return 'a_value';
      } else if (key === 'another_string') {
        return 'another_value';
      }
    }
  } as ConfigService
}
```

So, as long as the signature for **getAppConfigValue** is the same as specified in the actual ConfigService, what the function does internally can be modified.