# TypeError: jasmine.createSpy(...).andCallFake is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, jasmine, jasmine-jquery

While using `andCallFake` function in Jasmine unit test, I am getting this error :

> TypeError: jasmine.createSpy(...).andCallFake is not a function

What can be missing?

Comment: can you please share the code ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jasmine: spyOn(obj, 'method').andCallFake or and.callFake?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22041745/jasmine-spyonobj-method-andcallfake-or-and-callfake)

Answer (score 4):

It should be

```
spyOn(target, 'method').and.callFake(...);
jasmine.createSpy().and.callFake(...); // alternatively
```

There is a dot between `and` and `callFake`. As the [documentation](https://jasmine.github.io/2.6/introduction#section-Spies:_%3Ccode%3Eand.callFake%3C/code%3E) states

Regards