# Jasmine spyOn with specific arguments

Tags: jasmine, spyon

Suppose I have

```
spyOn($cookieStore,'get').and.returnValue('abc');
```

This is too general for my use case.  Anytime we call

```
$cookieStore.get('someValue') -->  returns 'abc'
$cookieStore.get('anotherValue') -->  returns 'abc'
```

I want to setup a spyOn so I get different returns based on the argument:

```
$cookieStore.get('someValue') -->  returns 'someabc'
$cookieStore.get('anotherValue') -->  returns 'anotherabc'
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you had a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16198353/any-way-to-modify-jasmine-spies-based-on-arguments

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Any way to modify Jasmine spies based on arguments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16198353/any-way-to-modify-jasmine-spies-based-on-arguments)

Answer (score 54):

You can use [callFake](http://jasmine.github.io/2.0/introduction.html#section-Spies:_%3Ccode%3Eand.callFake%3C/code%3E):

```js
spyOn($cookieStore,'get').and.callFake(function(arg) {
    if (arg === 'someValue'){
        return 'someabc';
    } else if(arg === 'anotherValue') {
        return 'anotherabc';
    }
});
```

Answer (score 27):

To the ones using versions 3 and above of jasmine, you can achieve this by using a syntax similar to sinon stubs:

```
spyOn(componentInstance, 'myFunction')
      .withArgs(myArg1).and.returnValue(myReturnObj1)
      .withArgs(myArg2).and.returnValue(myReturnObj2);
```

details in: https://jasmine.github.io/api/edge/Spy#withArgs

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution is use the `expect().toHaveBeenCalledWith()` to check the parameters, example:

```
spyOn($cookieStore,'get').and.returnValue('abc');
$cookieStore.get('someValue') -->  returns 'abc';    

expect($cookieStore.get).toHaveBeenCalledWith('someValue');

$cookieStore.get('anotherValue') -->  returns 'abc'
expect($cookieStore.get).toHaveBeenCalledWith('anotherValue');
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way of achieving the same result would be.... (Ideal when you are writing unit tests without using a testbed)
declare the spy in root describe block

```
const storageServiceSpy = jasmine.createSpyObj('StorageService',['getItem']);
```

and inject this spy in the place of original service in the constructor

```
service = new StoragePage(storageServiceSpy)
```

and inside the it() block...

```
storageServiceSpy.getItem.withArgs('data').and.callFake(() => {})
```